# How can I get colors with "ls -l | more"?

Tags: bash, ls

ls -l gives me color coded output. Folders are blue, executables green, etc. These colors are gone when filtering thorough | more. Anyway to achieve both paged output and colors?

Comment: Can you give us a detailed explanation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with **[less](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_less.htm)** command with repaint(-R) option:

```
ls --color=always -l | less -R
```

Comment: That works, and actually more as pager also works.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-R` (only change is uppercase R)?  [See here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uless.htm) for why...

Comment: @Breakthrough: +1. i'll update it.

Comment: Actually it also works with `more` with the `--color=always`, so that was the key for me!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for Mac OS X / BSD, but is fine for Linux

Comment: @user1442960 - that might be because Mac's `ls` doesn't take the `--color` option? Try `ls -G -l | less -R`, or, `brew install coreutils` to get `gnu ls`.

Comment: @dwanderson `ls -G -l | less -R` also doesn't work (it removes the color).  I agree gnu ls should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
ls -lA --color=always | more
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for the term "escape sequence" in the `man` page of `less`. About the colorful stuff, see [ANSI escape code # Colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors);

There is a detailed solution [on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19718/how-to-activate-pagination-for-ls-command) on how to have *paged & colored* output; the key info is:

```
ls -C --color=always | less -R
```